# Windows 10 explorer.exe opens Unix-like file paths in browser, resolves to odd domains

Tags: firefox, windows-explorer, path

I forgot I was on a Windows (10) machine and accidentally typed "/tmp" into the path textbox at the top of the file explorer.  Interestingly, it opened Firefox (99) and navigated to https://www.radancy.com/.  I was curious so I tried a few more, but ended up even more confused:

| File explorer path | URL opened in Firefox |
| --- | --- |
| /tmp | https://www.radancy.com/ |
| /tm | https://www.testmasters.com/ |
| /github | https://github.com/ |
| /google | https://google (no .com!) |

I did some searching and found a possible explanation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-dns-client-usedomainnamedevolution

That could make sense for the cases where it simply adds `.com`, but where would radancy and testmasters come from?  On a different machine, `/tmp` goes to https://www.tmp.com instead, but `/tm` still goes to testmasters.

Does anyone have an idea why these paths would behave this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that all these websites have registered multiple
domain names.

Windows Explorer, when faced with an input it can't understand,
will naively stick `www.` in front and `.com` at the end,
then pass the whole string to the default browser.

For example:

- https://www.tmp.com is registered by https://www.radancy.com/
- https://www.tm.com is registered by https://www.testmasters.com/

Your other examples are simpler to understand, such as `github`
becoming `https://github.com/`.

Comment: Where did you find who registered those domains?  I don't see any mention of those in the whois records.

Github makes sense, but what about Google missing the .com?

Either way, thanks for the informative answer.

Comment: I used Wireshark to see that this is what happened when entering these into Explorer. You can enter for example https://www.tmp.com to see that you fall on radancy.com. This is typical for a company that swallowed another, or that rebranded itself, keeping the old address to be used by old customers.

Comment: Of course, was just waiting for the question to be _fully_ answered which it was not before :)